# PrimeNg overlayPanel wrapping panelMenu

Tags: angular, primeng

`p-panelMenu` seem to work fine by itself.
When I put it inside a `p-overlayPanel` it has this issue:

- as soon as the overlay gets hidden all the nodes with children inside the panelMenu are expanded even if `"multiple=false"`
- panelMenu seem to consider the nodes as collapsed as it takes two clicks on each node to make it display as closed

Any idea why this happens?

Here is stackblitz example (I was not able to make primeicons work there but the issue is the same with or without icons): 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkw7bt

Comment: I feel like this could be related to this: MenuItem has an expanded property to control the visibility of a submenu, you may use this property to control the state from the menumodel. [state](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=22813) and [this](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781788299572/7/ch07lvl1sec74/panelmenu--hybrid-of-accordion-and-tree)

Comment: I have played with it; set/unset; issue is there either way; The problem happens only on the first hiding of the overlay menu; If all nodes are closed by clicking them twice, the problem no longer happens after